# Why don't animal cells have both mitochondria and chloroplasts?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-evolution

Ancestral eukaryotes had both mitochondria and chloroplasts, why do animal cells only have mitochondria. Why did evolution allow animal cells to give up such a great circle of energy? Where the waste of mitochondria contributes to photosynthesis and vice versa. Is this to the weakness of the animal cell membrane, which cannot hold as much water as animal cells? Though oval-shaped blood cells in camels allow them to consume large amounts of water since the cells are more elastic and can change shape more easily. So why? Just curious. Or is there something I’m missing.

Comment: Welcome  Christian. This is not simply a Q&A site, here we are expected to show the results of our own investigations into a subject here, you can [edit] to tell us what your searches found and where the sticking points are. You should also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to the ways of any site you post on, see our section on [how to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: "Ancestral eukaryotes had both mitochondria and chloroplasts". Please clarify and justify this statement with a reference. Are you talking about the same ancestor, and ancestor to what? I know of no evidence that animal cells ever had chloroplasts to "give up".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is either under researched or extremely unclear — it appears to be based on an incorrect assumption about eukaryotic evolution. Please do some reading on this subject and then either [edit] or delete this question based on the other users suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As evolution progressed and still is on the run, heterotrophs, i.e., the non-photosynthetic organisms did no longer need the endosymbiont cell organelles except mitochondria for their energy requirements. As a result, chloroplasts evolved to be vestigial and eventually non-existent. But exceptions do occur in nature. Chloroplasts can be actually found in non-plant eukaryotes. This phenomenon is called kleptoplasty, where an organism can generate energy from the chloroplast even without performing photosynthesis. For further read, check this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4517925/

Comment: From [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* ——— Please consider deleting this post as it is encouraging the posting of questions that are not appropriate for this site — please see the [tour] and other [help] pages such as [ask] and [answer] for more information. ——— In addition, your answer is almost certainly wrong — I encourage you to read your linked paper more carefully and consult other sources to correct this misapprehension.